# How to make GNU-Screen share 1 Screen for all Users?

Tags: linux, shell, centos, gnu-screen, multi-user

How can I start a Screen that is accesable as Root-User and Default-User?
Because now when I start a Screen as Default-User with the command:

```
screen -dmS test java $JAR nogui
```

After executing the command and logging in into Root-User and try to use

```
screen -x test
```

It will say, it doesn't exist, because Screen are User-Bound, AFAIK.

So is there a way that the screen is shared to all users ?
So I can attach the Screen by the Screen name from any user.

Answer (score 10):

You can enable multiuser, and add the permitted user to your list, like this:

```
# userA opens a screen
screen -S test

# set multiuser
Ctrl-A :multiuser on

# add the user to join your session to the ACL list:
Ctrl-A :acladd root
```

then

```
# root get the screen by userA
screen -x userA/test
```

[This](http://blog.boreas.ro/2010/04/share-gnu-screen-sessions-with.html) and [this](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser) are recommend.